# Snowflake External Stage file name pattern match not working

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a Select query on multiple files placed on External Stage(s3). The file names are

```
SAMPLE_FILE_NAME_20201014_155022.csv
SAMPLE_FILE_NAME_20201016_092711.csv
SAMPLE_FILE2_NAME2_20201014_155022.csv
SAMPLE_FILE2_NAME2_20201016_092711.csv
```

Want to select only the files with name SAMPLE_FILE_NAME.* If I query like below then it is not able to find any files or data

```
select $1 as col1, $2 as col2, $3 as col3, $4 as col4
FROM @ROLE1_ID1.LOCATION_ESTG (file_format => 'SEMICOLON', PATTERN => '.*SAMPLE_FILE_NAME.csv.*') t;
```

If I do like below then both SAMPLE_FILE_NAME & SAMPLE_FILE2_NAME2 get selected and I get incorrect data

```
select $1 as col1, $2 as col2, $3 as col3, $4 as col4
FROM @ROLE1_ID1.LOCATION_ESTG (file_format => 'SEMICOLON', PATTERN => '.*_20201014_155022.csv') t;
```

I tried several combinations of REGEXP but they don't seem to work while reading the external stage. For Ex. I tried `'SAMPLE_FILE_NAME.*\.csv'` which didn't work. What can be the correct expression to filter `SAMPLE_FILE_NAME*` and make the select work

Answer (score 2):

The `.*SAMPLE_FILE_NAME.csv.*` pattern does not work because `.` before `csv` only  matches any *single* char, while there are many more chars between `NAME` and `csv`.

You can use

```
'SAMPLE_FILE_NAME_.*\\.csv'
```

If the path includes directory name, you might need to add `.*` at the start and use

```
'.*SAMPLE_FILE_NAME_.*\\.csv'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KlAPpd/1)

Note that to match a literal dot, you need to escape it with a backslash, and since it can form string escape sequences in the string literals, it needs doubling.